# how to convert byte[100] to guid

Tags: c#, arrays, guid

I am receiving a service response which is `byte[100]` how can i convert it to a guid ?

```
byte[] response = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", nvc);
string Guid = new Guid(response).ToString();
Response.Write(Guid);
```

Comment: What is the encoding of the byte array ?

Comment: It seems you already have a solution. Does that not work for you? What does it do then?

Comment: If you're looking to create a unique signature based on the result value, I would suggest you calculate a hash-value instead, such as [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Guid constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90ck37x3.aspx) which allows you to initialize a Guid from a 16-element byte array. So you will have to first extract the 16 elements from your 100 elements array into a new one and then initialize the Guid. Which 16 elements to extract from your 100 elements array would of course depend.

Now I suspect that what happens here is that the server sends the Guid as a string in the response. So all you have to do is [parse it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse.aspx) after converting the response from the server into a string using the proper encoding:

```
byte[] response = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", nvc);
var guid = Guid.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response));
```

Comment: or be lazy: `new Guid(response.Take(16).ToArray())`

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen, in fact I don't think that this is indeed the OP problem here. See my updated answer. That's usually what happens when people do not properly explain and provide details in their questions: they confuse everyone and we only have to guess.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I also found the question rather confusing.

Comment: my returned response is byte[100] not 16

Comment: @Miroo, Guid does have a static Parse method, I have even linked to the documentation of it in my answer and also provided you with an example at the end. Did you read my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your code snippet, but Guid has overloads for [new (byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90ck37x3.aspx) and a [ToByteArray Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray.aspx) to transform Guids from and into Byte-Arrays - that should do the trick