# Convert a Guid to byte[16] in C#

Tags: c#, guid

I have converted Byte[16] to Guid using new Guid(byte[16]) constructor. Now I would like to convert back my guid to byte[16] to compare them, is it possible to do it ?

Comment: [`guid.ToByteArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray.aspx)?

Comment: As all the answers/comments link to the same article, your first port of call should be the documentation on MSDN.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray.aspx
previous stackoverflow post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298672/how-to-convert-byte100-to-guid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just use [`Guid.ToByteArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Use ToByteArray method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Guid has a `ToByteArray` method for exactly this.

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Sure - just use [`Guid.ToByteArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray.aspx).